# Get window token of the window to which decorview is attached

Tags: android, android-view, android-windowmanager, android-window

How to get the window token of the window to which decorview is attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, then this is my answer:

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().addOnAttachStateChangeListener(
        new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
          @Override public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
            IBinder binder = v.getWindowToken();
          }

          @Override public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {

          }
        });
```